# vb6 file write limit seems to be 0x4000

Tags: vb6

I have problem where the file write seems to stop 0x4000

```
For wrtCntr = 0 To lpNumDataBytesReturned - 1
    WriteDataBuffer_trans(wrtCntr) = TransposeBits(ReadDataBuffer(wrtCntr))
    Put #4, , WriteDataBuffer_trans(wrtCntr)
Next wrtCntr
 '' Ret = WriteFile(FileH, WriteDataBuffer_trans(0), lpNumDataBytesReturned, lpNumDataBytesReturnedCopy, 0&)
```

The file size always stops at 0x4000 and I cannot get it to go any further.
I am writing to `%TEMP%`

Anyone got any ideas.  I thought it was the problem with VB6 where ever it sets the Most significant bit the value is considered negative, but no matter what I try it will not write.

The file is open

```
sPathUser = Environ$("TEMP") & "\rd_out.txt"
```

Open sPathUser For Binary Access Write As #4

Thank you,
Martin

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I should add that the actual file size seems to be limited to 16.0 MB

Comment: There is no actual file size imposed by VB6 so it's definately a bug in your code that we cannot see because you forgot to post it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the file to grow, you are correct, I had a bug that was causing the program to exit prematurely at a 16Mb file size.  Sometimes an integer if you set it to 0x8000 it gets read as a negative number.  I thought I had cleared them all up but had missed one.  Thank you for your replies.